Node.js converting JSON file to a .txt file and format
Im trying to solve something i cant seem to find the answer to anywhere. Im collecting data and the spitting the data into a json file (intake.json) which contains an array of objects. Im trying to write a function that, when called, will take the intake.json file and write to a .txt file and then format the file.
When i console.log the element within the for loop is spits out every individual character...
ex:
D
a
t
e

:

0
6
/
1
2
/
2
4

Any help would be appreciated:
index.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const style =  require('node:util');

const yargs = require("yargs");
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({sigint: true});
const fs = require('node:fs');

console.clear();

const intakeType = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please Enter the intake type:'));
const date = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the intake date (mm/dd/yy): '));
const project = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please Enter the Project: '));
const reporter = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the reporter: '));
const team = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the team of the report: '));
const time = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the time taken: '));
const details = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the details of the intake: '));
const resolution = prompt(style.styleText('green','Please enter the resolution type: '));

const content = {
    intakeType,
    date,
    project,
    reporter,
    team,
    time,
    details,
    resolution
}

const JSONToFile = (obj) => {
    fs.readFile("intake.json", { flag: 'r' }, function(err, json) {
        var array = JSON.parse(json);
        array.push(obj);
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        fs.writeFile("intake.json", JSON.stringify(array, null, 2), { flag: 'w' }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("The intake was saved!");
        });
    });
}
JSONToFile(content);

// function to convert the json file to a .txt file
const convertToTxt = () => {
    fs.readFile("intake.json", "utf8", function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        const writtenData = []
        for (let index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
            const element = json[index];
            console.log('element', element);
            writtenData.push( `
                Date: ${element.date} \n
                Reporter: ${element.reporter} \n
                Time Taken: ${element.time} \n
                Team: ${element.team} \n
                Project: ${element.project} \n
                Intake Type: ${element.intakeType} \n
                Details: ${element.details} \n
                Resolution: ${element.resolution}\n\n
            `)
        }
        fs.writeFile("intake.txt", JSON.stringify(writtenData, null, 2), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(style.styleText('green','Text file successfully created'))
            }
        });
    });

}
convertToTxt('intake.json');


"I cant seem to get things right." - Could be you more specific about the problem you're encountering?

@David updated the question

You're iterating over a string, so, yeah… you'll see every character in it individually…!?

@deceze what flag do i pass to get the actual array instead of a Buffer?


When i console.log the element within the for loop is spits out every individual character

You're looping over a string:
fs.readFile("intake.json", "utf8", function(err, json) {
  //...

  // "json" is a string, the text that was read from the file
  for (let index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
    const element = json[index];
    console.log('element', element);
    //...
  }
  //...
});

When you loop over a string, each element in the loop is a single character of that string.  It sounds like you want to deserialize the JSON.  For example:
fs.readFile("intake.json", "utf8", function(err, json) {
  //...

  var array = JSON.parse(json); // <--- here
  // "array" is the array structure represented by the JSON in the file
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index];
    console.log('element', element);
    //...
  }
  //...
});

